# How to display data from two Firestore collections in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a React Native app using Firestore to store the data. I currently have two collections, one which stores booking information called "Booking", and other another containing user information called "User". The booking collections contains a user_id of the user involved in the booking.

I am currently trying to go through all of the bookings and extract the user_image of the user referenced in the booking from the user table. My code is as follows:

```
async retrieveSupplierImg(supplierId) {
    const userSnapshot = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("User")
      .doc(supplierId)
      .get();

    return {uri: userSnapshot.data().image};
  }
```

```
async getMeetings() {
    var meetings = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Booking")
      .where("status", "==", true)
      .where("consumer_id", "==", this.state.user_id)
      .get()


    this.setState({ appointments: meetings.docs.map(doc => {
       var image = this.retrieveSupplierImg(doc.data().supplier_id);
          return {
            supplier_id: doc.data().supplier_id,
            booking_id: doc.data().booking_id,
            start_time: doc.data().start_time,
            user_image: image
        }
    })});
}
```

```
renderBooking() {

      var meetings = this.state.appointments;
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          marginTop: 10,
          marginBottom: 10,
          width: width,
          height: height * 0.19,
          justifyContent: "flex-start",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        {meetings.map(booking => (

                <Image
                  source={booking.user_image}
                  style={{
                    height: 45,
                    width: 45,
                    borderRadius: 23,
                    marginLeft: 10
                  }}
                />

    );
  }
```

This code fails with the following error:

> You attempted to set the key `_65` with the value `1` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.

Does anyone have any idea of how I can fix this?

Comment: You need to synchronize between the retrieveSupplierImg call first and getMeetings() secondly , try to add async to this.retrieveSupplierImg

Comment: If I do that all the values become undefined

Comment: which values ? call your functions under ComponentDidMount

Comment: If I add async to the map inside the setstate in the getmeetings function, all of the values stored in the state are undefined when printed to the console

Comment: Desperately need some help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's an already solved issue. check this [link on Github](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/issues/179). you just need to change in where you are storing your promises (I guess userSnapshot and meetings) to `.then(value => {Asyncstorage.setitem()})`